# Ruby - how to effectively fetch data from hash according to a value

Tags: ruby, search, hash, key-value

I have hash like this (output of `SOURCE.inspect`):

> ```
> [{:id=>"1", :day=>"Monday", :message=>"... text ..."}, {:id=>"2", :day=>"Friday", :name=>"... message ..."}, ...]
> ```

I would need to fetch all "items" where **day == Monday**, but how to do that?
I've tried

```
SOURCE.select{|key, hash| hash[:day] == "Monday" }
```

But this is wrong... also, the file is quite big (almost 1MB of text), what's the best way to search in this hash?

Thank you

Comment: i don't think there's any other way but what you're currently using.

Comment: Have to examine each item anyway?

Comment: Depending on the possible values in the hash, you could do `SOURCE.select {|h| h.has_value? "Monday" }`. The reason I don't put this as an answer is because it would pick up any hash that contains "Monday" as a value anywhere in the `Hash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SOURCE.select {|x| x[:day] == "Monday" }
```

Comment: Hmm... I am trying this, but getting still only an empty array.

Comment: I tested it against your example and it works. Can you check your `SOURCE` please?

Answer (score 3):

`select` on an array gets you a single element--in your case, a hash.  So you can do it like this:

```
SOURCE.select { |hash| hash[:day] == "Monday" }
```